# c# WebBrowser SVG Windows 2008 R2

Tags: c#, browser, svg, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a WebBrowser in my C# application, in which i want to show a SVG file. However, when I run the app on a Windows 2008 R2 machine, the SVG file does not show up. 
When I have a look at the same file on the same server in Internet Explorer, everything looks ok.

What i already have tried:

- IE ESC settings on or off
- Trusted Sites / Local intranet sites
- Run 32 bits
- do the following override:

(from [this blog](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/01/03/flash-and-proxy-support-on-net-webbrowser-controls/))

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case 21:
                case 201:
                case 204:
                case 207:
                    base.DefWndProc(ref m);
                    return;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the Adobe plugin or something else?

Comment: Yes i've installed it in IE. Do you think i need to enable/load this plugin manually in this webbrowser? If so, how can i do that, because i can't find how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Data Execution Prevention (DEP). After switching this off, it works!